# Why this arithmetic expression is not equal?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, math, logic

In Visual studio 2010, c# .net while doing programming i found that the expressions

```
 var prs1 = (e.X * 100) / panel4.Width;            
 var prs2 = prs1;
 var ans = (prs2 * panel2.Width) / 100;            
 pb2.Location = new Point(ans, 30);
```

and another code:

```
var prs1 = (e.X / panel4.Width) * 100;
 var prs2 = prs1;
 var ans = (prs2 /100) * panel2.Width;
 pb2.Location = new Point(ans, 30);
 //this code giving incorrect response
```

please tell as mathematically both code are equal than why compiler is not giving me same output?

Comment: You're diving by integers, I'm pretty sure that's where the problem stems from. Can you extract the problem to one specific line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.X` looks like a X coordinate of an event handler. This is an integer value. The same for the `.Width` property.

Dividing value first may result in loss of precision, especially if the integer division results in 0. Multiplying by 100 afterwards still results in 0.

If you multiply by 100 first, it is more likely that the division is different to 0.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is rounding.

First part (e.X / panel4.width) of your second code very likely gives 0 as result:

lets say:

e.X = 40 and panel4.width = 250

then you get :

pr1 = (e.X / panel4.width); // 0.16 then it is rounding to 0
pr1 = pr1 * 100 // result is 0

You need to convert your values to double to get result of double then you can convert to "int" yourself later.

pr1 = Convert.ToDouble(e.X) / Convert.ToDouble(panel1.Width) * 100; // result is 16.0

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is not relate to airthmetic expression. Its just because of var  keyword.var  is used like  as generic types.if you initialize val like as int then you can not insert any string value in that or may be something else.
you got var ans like as double or int and you pass this to  [pb2.Location = new Point(ans, 30);] which is wrong.because point relate to another type.

Comment: I have no clue what you're trying to say here, to be honest. The problem is most likely integer division, not `var`.

Comment: var can be used in generics .i am not saying var is generics.

Comment: problem is relate to variable type that is assigned

Comment: Well, no. If you replace all 3 `var`s with `int` explicitly (which the compiler will implicitly do for you in this case), the problem would still exist.

Comment: And you did say "var is used like as generic types." That is a highly dubious statement. `var` (automatically compiler-inferred data types) and generics are two distinct and non-overlapping parts of the language.